# How to determine the laplace transform of $\cos(q(t))$?

Tags: trigonometry, laplace-transform

Good day I am currently determining the laplace transform of this equation with $q$ as the output angle and $T$ as the input torque to the system.

$$T = a \dfrac{d(q)}{dt} + b \cos(q)$$

and from my understanding, the Laplace transform of a derivative of a function $f$ is just

$$\frac {df(t)}{dt} \mapsto sF(s) - f(0)$$

and the derivative of a cosine function of $t$ is just

$$\cos(at) \mapsto \frac s {(s^2 + a^2)}$$

However my goal is to get the transfer function $\dfrac{Q(s)}{T(s)}$

From

$$T(t) = \left(a\dfrac {dq(t)}{dt}+b\cos(q(t))\right)$$

I am confused on whether I should do a linear approximation of $\cos(q(t))$ to make it $q(t)$ instead or consider $q$ as the variable itself instead. But if I do the latter, how do I factor out $Q(s)$ after performing the Laplace transform as the $q$ will just become $s$.

Comment: The maths text should be written using LaTeX.

Comment: @Mattos I'm sorry, I'll revise it accordingly

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: The transform of $dq(t)/dt$ is in fact $sQ(s)-q(0)$ as you already know.   

To get the transform of $cos(q(t))$ you need to be able to approximate it as a power series in time or  as a Fourier series if q(t) is periodical.